# Unknown stage section "withKubeConfig" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm going to deploy my docker image to the k8s cluster using jenkins CICD.

I installed Kubernetes CLI and SSH Agent in Jenkins.

I used the below code.

```
stage('List pods') {
    withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubectl-user']) {
        sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'  
        sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'  
        sh './kubectl get pods -n dev'
    }
  }
```

And, I'm getting the below error.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 39: Unknown stage section "withKubeConfig". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 39, column 2.
    stage('List pods') {
    ^

WorkflowScript: 39: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "List pods" @ line 39, column 2.
    stage('List pods') {
    ^

2 errors

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:571)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:523)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are using [scripted pipeline syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals) inside a declarative pipeline and therefore you are seeing the error.

If you  want to use declarative pipeline syntax you must follow the strict [formatting guidelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/), in your case you are missing the steps directive under the stage directive.
Your code should look something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage('List Pods') {
           steps {
               withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubectl-user']) {
                   sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'
                   sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'
                   sh './kubectl get pods -n dev'
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

If you want to use the scripted pipeline syntax it will look something like:

```
node {
    stage('List Pods') {
        withKubeConfig([credentialsId: 'kubectl-user']) {
            sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'
            sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'
            sh './kubectl get pods -n dev'
        }
    }
}
```

You can [read more here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#compare) about the differences between the two pipelines syntaxes.